# KVO not working (swift 2.2)?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing

- In my app, OneVC is one of child ViewControllers of PageViewController, TwoVC is the embed view controller of OneVC's Container View.
- When the user drag the scroll view in OneVC, I want the drag action can be not just update the content in OneVC from web API, but notify TwoVC to update too.
- Both OneVC and TwoVC will appear at interface at the same time when launch.

I'm following Apple's "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" "Key-Value Observing" instruction to imply KVO, but no notification is sent when the observed property changes. Please see below my code:

> OneVC is the object to be observed.

```
class OneVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
 dynamic var isDragToUpdate = false

 func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -150 {         
        if isDragToUpdate {
            isDragToUpdate = false
        } else {
            isDragToUpdate = true
        }

        print(isDragToUpdate)
    }
 }
}
```

> TwoVC is the observer

```
class TwoVC: UIViewController {
let oneVC = OneVC()

 override viewDidLoad() {
  oneVC.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isDragToUpdate", options: [], context: nil)
}

 override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    print("hoh")
    guard keyPath == "isDragToUpdate" else {return}
    print("hah")        
}

 deinit {
    oneVC.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isDragToUpdate")
}
}
```

I checked row by row, and find many other stackoverflow answers, but still no idea what's going wrong on my code, when drag and release the scrollview, none of "hoh" and "hah" are print in console, except print(isDragToUpdate) is printed properly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is a very unusual setup. If one view controller is observing another view controller, you've almost certainly violated MVC (view controllers should generally not communicate with each other, except in one-time hand-offs during transitions). Are both view controllers actually active at the same time (that's unusual)? Has `viewDidLoad` actually run? (And if so, why is there scrolling going on in another vie controller?) Almost certainly your problem is that `oneVC` is not the same instance you're scrolling (unless you're actually putting it onscreen somewhere in the code).

Comment: Are you sure that you are observing the same object that is generating the events? In your code you are creating a new `OneVC` for each `TwoVC`.

Comment: I'm very appreciate for your comments. In my app, OneVC is one of child ViewControllers of PageViewController, TwoVC is the embed view controller of OneVC's Container View. When the user drag the scroll view in OneVC, I want the drag action can be not just update the content in OneVC from web API, but notify TwoVC to update too. Both OneVC and TwoVC will appear at interface when app launch. In such situation, how to make sure I'm observing the same object that is generating the events?